# Function pointer as "tag" in tagged union

Tags: c, unions

One of the reasons why I tend to avoid using tagged unions is that I don't like the idea of the performance penalty that the `switch/case` statement for the tag might introduce if the number of tags is greater than 4 or so.

I just had the idea that instead of using a tag, one could set a pointer to a function that reads the last  written value in the `union`. For example:

```
union u{
   char a;
   int b;
   size_t c;
};

struct fntag{
   void (*readval)(union u *ptr, void *out);
   union u val;
};
```

And then, whenever you write a value into `val`, you also update the `readval` pointer accordingly, so that it points to a function that reads the last field you wrote in the union. Yes, there's a difficult issue, and it's where to return the read value (because the same function pointer cannot point to functions returning different types). I chose to return the value through a pointer to `void` so that such function can also be "overloaded" with C11 `_Generic()` and thus casting and writing into different types for the output.

Of course, invoking a pointer to a function has a performance overhead, and I guess it's far heavier that checking the value of an `enum`, but at some point, if the number of tags is big, I believe it would be faster than `switch/case`.

My question is: Have you ever seen this technique used somewhere? (I haven't, and I don't know if it's because real world application of this would require `_Generic()` on the readval function, which requires C11, or if it's because of some problem I'm not noticing at this moment). How many tags do you guess you'd need  to have for the pointer to function being faster -in current Intel CPUs- than the `switch/case`?

Comment: `switch/case` usually compiles into an indexed jump when all the cases are within a dense range of integers. So it doesn't get slower as the number of tags increases.

Comment: What you're designing is similar to the way the the virtual table works in OO languages.

Comment: *performance penalty that the `switch/case` statement for the tag might introduce if the number of tags is greater than 4 or so*  When did you profile your code and demonstrate that there even is such a performance penalty?

Comment: Using your technique, you'd probably need a switch anyway after reading the value to cast the pointer to the proper type.

Comment: Shame on me... I didn't know `switch/case` is usually optimized as an indexed jump. I always thought it was compiled as a nested `if`. In fact, I never understood why the Duff's device didn't suffer from the penalty of a nested `if` ...now I understand :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that. In your case a more optimization friendly function signature would be size_t `size_t (*)(union u U)` (all the union values can be sort of fitted into `size_t` and the union is small enough for passing by value to be more efficient), but even with that, function calls have non-negligible overhead that tends to be significantly larger than that of a jump through a switch-generated jump table.

Try something like:

```
#include <stddef.h>
enum en { e_a, e_b, e_c };
union u{
   char a;
   int b;
   size_t c;
};

size_t u_get_a(union u U) { return U.a; }
size_t u_get_b(union u U) { return U.b; }
size_t u_get_c(union u U) { return U.c; }

struct fntag{ size_t (*u_get)(union u U); union u u_val; };
struct entag{ enum en u_type; union u u_val; };

struct fntag fntagged1000[1000]; struct entag entagged1000[1000];

void init(void) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<1000; i++)
        switch(i%3){
        break;case 0: 
            fntagged1000[i].u_val.a = i, fntagged1000[i].u_get = &u_get_a;
            entagged1000[i].u_val.a = i, entagged1000[i].u_type = e_a;
        break;case 1: 
            fntagged1000[i].u_val.b = i, fntagged1000[i].u_get = &u_get_b;
            entagged1000[i].u_val.b = i, entagged1000[i].u_type = e_b;
        break;case 2:
            fntagged1000[i].u_val.c = i, fntagged1000[i].u_get = &u_get_c;
            entagged1000[i].u_val.c = i, entagged1000[i].u_type = e_c;
        }
}


size_t get1000fromEnTagged(void)
{
    size_t r = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        switch(entagged1000[i].u_type){
        break;case e_a: r+=entagged1000[i].u_val.a;
        break;case e_b: r+=entagged1000[i].u_val.b;
        break;case e_c: r+=entagged1000[i].u_val.c;
        /*break;default: __builtin_unreachable();*/
        }
    }
    return r;
}

size_t get1000fromFnTagged(void)
{
    size_t r = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) r += (*fntagged1000[i].u_get)(fntagged1000[i].u_val);
    return r;
}



int main(int C, char **V)
{
    size_t volatile r;
    init();
    if(!V[1]) for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) r=get1000fromEnTagged();
    else for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) r=get1000fromFnTagged();


}
```

At -O2, I'm getting more then twice the performance in the switch-based code.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, I've spent 30 years writing C without knowing that `switch/case` is usually optimized as a branch table. Shame on me!! Well, it's never too late to learn, but man... 30 years in ignorance of this :-)

Comment: @cesss The indirect jump has some overhead too which tends to be greater than the costs of a small couple of if tests. Some optimizing compilers do generate if tests if the number of cases is small and if the case labels are numerically far from each other (gcc seems more willing to do that and clang seems to like generating jump tables in my experience), which would lead to a large (and largely empty) jump table. Or you can get a combo of the two approaches. Or binary search through tests. Switches are not very low-level, but the basic expectation should be "jump table unless reasons".

Comment: @cesss If I may suggest a heuristic to avoid this problem in the future: when in doubt, the simplest code (the one that is easiest to *fully* understand and predict) is probably the most optimization-friendly, so optimizations for it are more likely to already exist, and are more likely to appear sooner.